# Use special character in acronym

Tags: acronyms

everyone! Hope you all are doing well!

My question is quite short:

Trying `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}`, it is not possible to do `\acro{R&D}{Research and Development}` nor `\acro{R\&D}{Research and Development}` to use `\ac{R&D}` or `\ac{R\&D}` in order to get *Research and Development (R&D)* as output result in the text. **How should I proceed?**

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide a complete MWE or your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at he acronym package documentation ([here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf)).

You can use `\acro{acronym}[short name]{full name}`.

e.g. `\acro{H2O}[$\mathrm{H_2O}$]{water} or \acro{rnd}[R\& D]{Research and Development}`

In short: the first field is the label (for referencing) the second is the short version and the final element is the long text.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much!